# Understanding the flow of this "forked" script

Tags: python, fork

I have got this code, and in order to understand it better I added a line to track where the pid is equal to zero:

```
import os, time
def counter(count): # run in new process
    for i in range(count):
        time.sleep(0.00001) # simulate real work
        print('[%s] => %s' % (os.getpid(), i))

for i in range(5):

    pid = os.fork()
    print("The pid is: ", pid)# the one I added
    if pid != 0:
        print('Process %d spawned' % pid) # in parent: continue
    else:
        counter(5) # else in child/new process
        os._exit(0) # run function and exit
print('Main process exiting.')
```

Questions:

1) what activates the call to counter? are the new processes checking their pid and if this is equal to zero, then call to counter?

2) If I change the sleep time to 1 second (instead of tenths of mils), then no data for child processes is printed. What is going on in the background then ?

I got this result:

```
the pid is:  6                                                                                                                                                                     
Prociss 6 spawned                                                                                                                                                                 
the pid is:  7                                                                                                                                                                     
Prociss 7 spawned                                                                                                                                                                 
the pid is:  8                                                                                                                                                                     
Prociss 8 spawned                                                                                                                                                                 
the pid is:  9                                                                                                                                                                     
Prociss 9 spawned                                                                                                                                                                 
the pid is:  10                                                                                                                                                                    
Prociss 10 spawned                                                                                                                                                                
Main prociss exiting.                                                                                                                                                             
the pid is:  0                                                                                                                                                                     
the pid is:  0                                                                                                                                                                     
the pid is:  0                                                                                                                                                                     
the pid is:  0                                                                                                                                                                     
[6] => 0                                                                                                                                                                          
[8] => 0                                                                                                                                                                          
[7] => 0                                                                                                                                                                          
[6] => 1                                                                                                                                                                          
the pid is:  0                                                                                                                                                                     
[8] => 1                                                                                                                                                                          
[6] => 2                                                                                                                                                                          
[7] => 1                                                                                                                                                                          
[9] => 0                                                                                                                                                                          
[6] => 3                                                                                                                                                                          
[8] => 2                                                                                                                                                                          
[7] => 2                                                                                                                                                                          
[9] => 1                                                                                                                                                                          
[8] => 3                                                                                                                                                                          
[6] => 4                                                                                                                                                                          
[7] => 3                                                                                                                                                                          
[8] => 4                                                                                                                                                                          
[7] => 4                                                                                                                                                                          
[9] => 2                                                                                                                                                                          
[10] => 0                                                                                                                                                                         
[9] => 3                                                                                                                                                                          
[10] => 1                                                                                                                                                                         
[9] => 4                                                                                                                                                                          
[10] => 2                                                                                                                                                                         
[10] => 3                                                                                                                                                                         
[10] => 4                                                                                                                                                                         


...Program finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The new process is an almost-exact copy of the old one.

Comment: What's interesting is why the child processes aren't printing from 0 to 4. Something is killing them after the main process exits, but not immediately.

Comment: What you're asking for is, basically, a tutorial on `fork`. That's not something that can be written as a good Stack Overflow answer. And a link to an external tutorial is also not a good Stack Overflow answer. Fortunately, there are definitely some good tutorials out there, although most of them are for C rather than Python, but you'll need to find a site that's more discussion-oriented than Q&A-oriented to get some good recommendations to start with.

Comment: I can give you the short version: after `fork`, you have two processes with the same loaded program, memory heap, file descriptors, etc., but in the child `fork` has returned 0, while in the parent, it's returned the child's PID. There are a few minor differences (most obviously, who the parent of each process is, and whether each process has any children…), but for the most part they don't matter. One place they _do_ matter is shutdown, for which you have to understand how child reaping and signals and so on all work, which is not trivial, but all well documented.

Comment: yes, I am aware  of any fork tutorial outside, but I am trying to understand this code in specific, that was the question, not so much how fork works,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your two questions:

> what activates the call to counter? are the new processes checking their pid and if this is equal to zero, then call to counter?

Yes. `os.fork()` is an unusual beast, in that it "violates the laws of physics": it returns *twice*, in two separate processes. The two processes are (nearly) identical, so the *only* way to know which one you are (the parent or the child) is to see what `os.fork()` returned: if it returned zero, you are the child, otherwise the return value is the pid of the child.

Since both processes execute the `if pid != 0` line, the one where the pid *is* zero (that is, the child) will execute the `else` block, which will call `counter`.

> If I change the sleep time to 1 second (instead of tenths of mils), then no data for child processes is printed. What is going on in the background then ?

You are not `wait`ing for your children. This means that as soon as the parent process exits, it "orphans" all its child processes. `init` will helpfully adopt them, but they may lose access to their controlling terminal in the process, and that alone may be enough to kill them. Also, on a modern Linux system, `systemd` will likely kill the children if you haven't told it otherwise.

Generally, if you are using `fork`, you need to also `wait`. The parent gets the pid of the child that was forked so that it can call `wait` on that pid. This serves two purposes: first, it actually waits for the child to be done executing, and secondly it will allow the parent to receive the exit code from the child, which will allow you to know if the child exited successfully or if it was killed. If you're not waiting, there's no 100% reliable way to know what happened to the child. (Even if you stash the pid somewhere else, it's possible that the pid could get reused before you get a chance to check again.)

There are a lot of subtleties in the dance of `fork`/(`exec`)/`wait`; there is an elegance in their simplicity but there is a *lot* of assumed knowledge if you are touching these tools. Do not expect to be able to use `fork` effectively if you *haven't* read any tutorials on it. And if you don't want to become an expert on the Unix process model (and things like signal handling, controlling terminals and session leaders, etc.) then you're much better off using a higher-level abstraction to solve the problem rather than mucking about with low-level stuff like this. Python helpfully provides the `multiprocessing` module to help with this, which is a much better tool for general-purpose use.

Comment: yes, I have studied the chapters on threading and their locks, rlocks, queues, conditions, events, barriers, and multiprocessing with pools and maps, and applies,. but the book also had this section on forking and I never skip things lest that I should miss concepts that may come up later. Thank you.